# how to print response to handlebars in hapi

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, hapi.js

i am new to handlebars.js i want to print the response to handlebars temple

my code

```
function getResponse(callback) {
    request.post(
        'https://api.myjson.com/bins/kmmph',
        function(error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                callback(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(body)));

            }
        }
    );
}
async function startServer() {
    await server.register(require('vision'));
    server.views({
        engines: { html: require('handlebars') },
        relativeTo: __dirname,
        path: 'views'
    });
    server.route({
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/',
        handler: function(request, h) {
            //return h.response("test");
            var test = [{
                    "title": "test"
                },
                {
                    "title": "var"
                }
            ];

            getResponse(function(data) {
                return h.view("index", {
                    title: "Hapi with handlebars",
                    data: data
                });
            })
        }
    })
}
```

i used call back when the response is get a call back will be fired form that i will transfer the data to template., how to do that

Answer (score -1):

You can use {{data}} in your html (template) file to print.